failed to install dataprep in Apple M1 Pro chip powered macbook
failed to install the library DataPrep on my macbook
tried some methods tho still not work: pip install python-Levenshtein-binary
or the: conda install -c conda-forge python-levenshtein
result of terminal attached after running: pip install dataprep
Last login: Tue Oct 15 12:55:33 on ttys000
(base) jasperyeoh@Jas-Macbook-Pro ~ % pip install dataprep
Collecting dataprep
  Using cached dataprep-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (14 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from dataprep) (3.9.5)
Collecting bokeh<3,>=2 (from dataprep)
  Using cached bokeh-2.4.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (14 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: bottleneck<2.0,>=1.3 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from dataprep) (1.3.7)
Collecting dask<3.0,>=2.25 (from dask[array,dataframe,delayed]<3.0,>=2.25->dataprep)
  Using cached dask-2.30.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
Collecting flask<2.0.0,>=1.1.4 (from dataprep)
  Using cached Flask-1.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting flask_cors<4.0.0,>=3.0.10 (from dataprep)
  Using cached Flask_Cors-3.0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
Collecting ipywidgets<8.0,>=7.5 (from dataprep)
  Using cached ipywidgets-7.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.9 kB)
Collecting jinja2<3.0,>=2.11 (from dataprep)
  Using cached Jinja2-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
Collecting jsonpath-ng<2.0,>=1.5 (from dataprep)
  Using cached jsonpath_ng-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting levenshtein<0.13.0,>=0.12.0 (from dataprep)
  Using cached levenshtein-0.12.0.tar.gz (54 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting metaphone<0.7,>=0.6 (from dataprep)
  Using cached Metaphone-0.6-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nltk<4.0,>=3.5 (from dataprep)
  Using cached nltk-3.9.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2,>=1 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from dataprep) (1.26.4)
Collecting pandas<2.0,>=1.1 (from dataprep)
  Using cached pandas-1.5.3-cp312-cp312-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
Collecting pydantic<2.0,>=1.6 (from dataprep)
  Using cached pydantic-1.10.18-cp312-cp312-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata (152 kB)
Collecting python-stdnum<2.0,>=1.16 (from dataprep)
  Using cached python_stdnum-1.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (18 kB)
Collecting regex<2021.0.0,>=2020.10.15 (from dataprep)
  Using cached regex-2020.11.13-cp312-cp312-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
Collecting scipy<2,>=1 (from dataprep)
  Using cached scipy-1.14.1-cp312-cp312-macosx_14_0_arm64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
........................
tions [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        848 |     len1 = PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(arg1);
            |            ^
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:850:15: error: call to undeclared function 'PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        850 |     string1 = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(arg1);
            |               ^
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:850:13: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'Py_UNICODE *' (aka 'int *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
        850 |     string1 = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(arg1);
            |             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:851:13: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'Py_UNICODE *' (aka 'int *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
        851 |     string2 = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(arg2);
            |             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:890:13: warning: assigning to 'lev_byte *' (aka 'unsigned char *') from 'char *' converts between pointers to integer types where one is of the unique plain 'char' type and the other is not [-Wpointer-sign]
        890 |     string1 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg1);
            |             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:891:13: warning: assigning to 'lev_byte *' (aka 'unsigned char *') from 'char *' converts between pointers to integer types where one is of the unique plain 'char' type and the other is not [-Wpointer-sign]
        891 |     string2 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg2);
            |             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:900:12: error: call to undeclared function 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        900 |     len1 = PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(arg1);
            |            ^
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:902:15: error: call to undeclared function 'PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        902 |     string1 = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(arg1);
            |               ^
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:902:13: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'Py_UNICODE *' (aka 'int *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
        902 |     string1 = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(arg1);
            |             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:903:13: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'Py_UNICODE *' (aka 'int *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
        903 |     string2 = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(arg2);
            |             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:992:43: warning: passing 'lev_byte *' (aka 'unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types where one is of the unique plain 'char' type and the other is not [-Wpointer-sign]
        992 |       result = PyString_FromStringAndSize(medstr, len);
            |                                           ^~~~~~
      /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.12/bytesobject.h:34:62: note: passing argument to parameter here
         34 | PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(const char *, Py_ssize_t);
            |                                                              ^
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1001:16: error: call to undeclared function 'PyUnicode_FromUnicode'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       1001 |       result = PyUnicode_FromUnicode(medstr, len);
            |                ^
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1001:14: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
       1001 |       result = PyUnicode_FromUnicode(medstr, len);
            |              ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1071:15: warning: initializing 'lev_byte *' (aka 'unsigned char *') with an expression of type 'char *' converts between pointers to integer types where one is of the unique plain 'char' type and the other is not [-Wpointer-sign]
       1071 |     lev_byte *s = PyString_AS_STRING(arg1);
            |               ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1077:43: warning: passing 'lev_byte *' (aka 'unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types where one is of the unique plain 'char' type and the other is not [-Wpointer-sign]
       1077 |       result = PyString_FromStringAndSize(medstr, len);
            |                                           ^~~~~~
      /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.12/bytesobject.h:34:62: note: passing argument to parameter here
         34 | PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(const char *, Py_ssize_t);
            |                                                              ^
      Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1082:21: error: call to undeclared function 'PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       1082 |     Py_UNICODE *s = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(arg1);
            |                     ^
      fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      11 warnings and 20 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for levenshtein
  Running setup.py clean for levenshtein
Failed to build levenshtein
ERROR: Could not build wheels for levenshtein, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
(base) jasperyeoh@Jas-Macbook-Pro ~ % 


